# Can I detect document.readyState - like events on a completely dynamically loaded page?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I currently am building a web page that is loading its subpages with an `AJAX` request while using `history.push` for navigation. Therefore the browser will need to cache various resources before displaying them on URL change.
While my code is loading the next page by AJAX (needs to be plain `$.ajax`, not `$.load`, because I not only fetch the page content but other data too) I am displaying a loading screen.

Problem: I want to display this screen as long as the browser takes for loading every single resource on the upcoming page, to prevent missing images or videos when lifting the blindfold. On the first load, I can manage this by listening for `onreadystatechange` or. `$(document).ready()` - but how can I achieve this when using dynamic loading?

Is there a way to "relisten" to the `readyStateChange` event or any other possibility to resolve this issue?

Best regards
Lukas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can track each ajax request using `.ajaxSend` and `.ajaxComplete`.

When there are no more outstanding ajax requests, close your loading splash screen.  If the close is in doc.ready, then it will run immediately if the doc is already ready.

```
var xhrCount = 0;
$(document).ajaxSend(function (e, jqXHR, options) {
    xhrCount++;
});
$(document).ajaxComplete(function (e, jqXHR, options) {
    xhrCount--;
    if (xhrCount === 0)  {
        $(function() { closeLoadingScreen(); });
    }
});
```

See [Global Ajax Event Handlers](https://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/) for more info.